# Ssh with JSch to a remote machine that asks twice for username and password

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I am just doing `ssh me1@ipaddress` to a remote machine, where I can't understand what is happening. This command again asks for username and password twice like this:

```
$ ssh me1@ip

username : me2
password :
```

I am using JSch which allows specifying one set of username and password like shown below syntax:

```
new JSch().getSession(userName, connectionIP, connectionPort)
```

But in this scenario, we need to provide **two usernames** as `me1` and `me2`.

How can I achieve this using JSch or any other library in Java?

Comment: Show us more code. what do you do after `getSession`?

Comment: What happens if you only do `ssh ipaddress` (no `me1@`)? What does the username/password prompts look like then? The `username`/`password` prompt you get could be from a command started when you have logged in, i.e. something that doesn't have anything to do with ssh.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson without `me1@`, It directly asks for password but as expected it doesn't match with my password.

Comment: So, no question for a username? Maybe your ssh client is set up to use a default username?

Comment: @RogerGustavsson No. No. Only with `me1@`, it asks again for `username :` and `password :` as shown above. Without that it directly asks password and my password, doesn't match there. ..! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ssh`  commands starts a shell session. The prompts for the credentials are just regular I/O prompts, as any other. Nothing credentials-specific. So you should provide the input the way, you would provide any other input – by writing it to the shell input stream.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious deficiency within my question. Just wondering: s there any specific purpose or reasoning why one have or want to use "two" login names like this?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to solve this with `Shell` Channel Type which is very much fit to your answer.

Comment: As I 've changed to my implementation channel type from `exec` to `shell`. It works fine. Thanks and Happy learning...! :)

Comment: @GhostCat No idea. It's actually possible that the `me1` it not really needed. Maybe the only real login is the `me2`. Some legacy devices that switched from Telnet to SSH do that - They do not use SSH authentication mechanism, but keep the old Telnet-like I/O prompts.